# How to use a WPF "behavior" in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've got an application, written by my predecessor, which uses WPF, but I'm really not very familiar with it.

I've had to take a DLL he had compiled, fetch the source code from [this webpage](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/BusyIndicator) and convert it to VB, because the compiled DLL, which had worked on desktop installations in the past, refused to work on our terminal servers.

So, I have taken the C# code, and converted the

```
public static class BusyIndicatorBehavior
```

to

```
Public Module BusyIndicatorBehavior
```

I have removed the top-level namespace (namespace ScrumSprintMonitor.UI.Wpf.Behaviors) because I really don't know what it's supposed to represent and now, frankly, I have no idea how to reference this in the XAML code I have.

The existing code is as follows:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="{Binding Path=WindowTitle}"
UseLayoutRounding="True"

xmlns:l="clr-namespace:myAppName"
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:BusyIndicator;assembly=BusyIndicator" WindowState="Maximized">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF8B8B8B" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF484848" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="grdFolder" b:BusyIndicatorBehavior.BusyState="{Binding Path=BusyState}">
```

As you can see, the previously-working DLL was called "BusyIndicator.DLL", is referenced with the namespace "b", and b is then made into a property of Grid. Somehow. Magically.

Can someone take a guess as to how I can reference the "BusyIndicator" code I've got now from the existing project? I realise I've probably left out a load of important information, but I'm running pretty clueless, here.

Comment: What do you mean by " how I can reference the "BusyIndicator" code I've got now from the existing project"? If the code above works you already have a reference.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The code above is the existing code, which references a DLL. This DLL does not work on our terminal servers. I have gotten what I believe to be the source cod to that DLL, and have integrated it into my code. What I have now is some working (hopefully) VB code, but non-working XAML which must be altered to take into account the change that BusyIndicator is now integral to the project rather than external. The code above is the original code and does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, after your comment it seems more clear to me.

All that is needed is to add the correct namespace to the xaml.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="{Binding Path=WindowTitle}"
    UseLayoutRounding="True"

    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:myAppName"
    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:********" WindowState="Maximized">
```

At the spot of the `********` you have to insert the namespace in which the BusyIndicator class is placed. If you are writing in VB.NET, have a look at the root namespace in the properties of the project. Notice that I removed the assembly part of the xmlns.

If the namespace of the BusyIndicator is myAppName you could remove the b alias and replace it in the xaml by `l` which refers to that namespace.

Comment: AUGH! I had tried doing that, but it did not work, because I had to remove all of the references to "BusyIndicatorBehaviour", compile, and then add the references back in. I had forgotten that "feature" of WPF. Thank you. Knowing that I was approaching from the right direction made me explore other reasons why it was not working.